# Drupal 7: Link Image Field Module

Tags: navigation, media

I would like to link 2 images to their own external url using link image field.
I've tried adding the following codes under "rewrite results" but it doesn't work.

```
<a href=[field_social_links-url]>[field_social_links]</a>
```

I suspect [field_social_links-url] still includes the internal URL. What can i do? Please advise.

Comment: First off, always enclose attribute values with quotation marks (I.e., put quotation marks around "[field_social_links-url]". Secondly, what is it actually outputting? I.e., what's the code for whatever shows up in the View preview?

Comment: @aendrew, I've found my error. It's actually to add http:// in front of the link instead of just www.xxx.com for instance, using external URL.

Comment: You should answer your own question with that information and then mark that as the answer, in that case. Helps other people with similar questions find this one and just keeps the community healthy. Thanks!